# Webview resize to big when EditText is selected

Tags: android

When I select the EditText in the web interface, softkeyboard appeared but too big.
This caused me to not lose EditText. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

//Please try to use bellow code.

FrameLayout mFrame;

```
 @Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

```
mFrame = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    mFrame.setPadding(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
    setContentView(mFrame);
    mFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mContent = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    mContent.setPadding(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
    mFrame.addView(mContent);

    PaintDrawable background = new PaintDrawable(Color.BLACK);
    background.setAlpha(BORDER_ALPHA);
    background.setCornerRadius(BORDER_RADIUS);
    mContent.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

    setUpWebView();
```

}

private void setUpWebView() {

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    mWebView = (WebView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_layout, null);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

    mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());

    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

    mContent.addView(mWebView);
}
```